# Maturity and usability of retropie project + kodi VS kodi + Rom collection

Tags: kodi, retropie

Currently I have installed retropie on my pi2. 
It serves as my retro gaming device over blutooth with my ps3 controllers.

However I have also installed Kodi via retropi and find myself using it for kodi more than for gaming.

I'm contemplating of flashing OSMC over the retropie install and using the RCB / Kodi game emulator addon for infrequent gaming.

Has anyone used both? I don't have much spare time to play around with this anymore, so I just want to set it up and forget about it.

Should I flash? or isn't Kodi + gaming addon mature enough to compete with retropie?

Comment: Do you have some requirements on what you need the platform to do? Specific gaming systems/games, emulation, Steam streaming...? At the moment your question is looking for opinions, which isn't the best fit for the site.

Comment: I know the question is a bit opinion based, however I'm looking for facts in favor or against one or the other. My requirement is more in terms of "eas of use". Not switching from emulationstation to kodi, setting up a controler scheme once, etc, ...

Comment: I think there's an objective question in there although you might have to wait a long time for someone to come along and say,  "Yeah, I've done that and it is fine".   How about option C) *Get a 2nd SD card*?  There's a lot of complex software involved here that may or may not have someone(s) out there into making sure all the pieces are going to fit together nicely.  If what you have now works, why ditch it?   You've said you don't have much time to play around with this, so maybe the $10-15 for another card will be worth the potential hassle saved so you can fool around a bit stress free.

Comment: Feel free to modify my question into something that smells less of an opinionated question. I would have to go out of my way to buy another card, since I'm using my "spare" in another project. I'll keep this question going though. Who knows, maybe I'll be the one answering it in the end ... still curious :)